# Activity's background thread & configuration change

Tags: android, multithreading, configuration, android-activity, orientation

I have seen some discussion here on Stack Overflow related to using Activity.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() to maintain a background thread started by one instance of an Activity and pass it to the next instance of the Activity which results, for example, when the phone's orientation changes from portrait to landscape.

The discussions do not specify exactly what can be done with the thread wrapped in the Object returned from onRetainNonConfigurationInstance().

For example:
1. Is there a way to actually keep the background thread running using this technique? 
2. Do you need to somehow pause the thread when the previous instance of Activity is going away and then restart it again in the new instance?

Can anyone provide a short example?

Any details would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return anything you want to `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`. If you have a Thread that you want passed from one instance of the Activity to another, you can either return it directly, or put it inside another object that you return from `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`. You don't need to pause the thread or interact with it in any way. It just keeps running as if nothing happened.

The only thing you need to be concerned about is how the Thread interacts with the Activity (if at all). If the thread will call the Activity back (to indicate progress or something like that) then you somehow need to give the thread a reference to the new Activity, as the old Activity will be dead.

What do you want to do in your background thread?

**EDIT (add more details about threads/activities):**

Threads have their own lifetimes which are completely disconnected from Activities. If you create a Thread in an Activity and start it, it will run to completion no matter what your Activity does. The only thing that will stop the thread explicitly is if Android decides to kill your process (which it may do if your process contains no active activities).

Comment: The background thread started by the Activity has no direct reference to the Activity or the Context. When the Activity creates the thread, it passes two collections to the thread which the thread will populate. So the Activity and the background thread share references to these collections. The background thread parses xml files and loads images over the internet. When the thread returns after a few seconds, the Activity can then access the images and other data from the two collections that it passed to the background thread.

Comment: Then you have no problem. The thread just continues to do its thing. You just pass a reference from the old activity to the new activity.

Comment: Actually my background thread does refer to the Activity. It is currently an inner-class of the Activity and makes a call to Activity.runOnUiThread(...) when it finishes its background work. The code that it runs on the UI thread makes a call to use the downloaded images to update the View and makes another call to dismiss the ProgessDialog.

Comment: That may be a problem (depending on how you are doing things). I would figure out a way for the new instance of the Activity to tell the thread to call it back instead (for example, don't use an inner class, or use a static inner class and pass a reference to the activity to the thread, which you can later change if a new instance of the activity is created).

Answer (score 0):

The thread will continue to run.  For an example of what you can do with this, you can check out the android [Ignition](https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition) project and its `IgnitedAsyncTask` (and related examples).

The idea is that you will maintain a reference to your thread (usually an `AsyncTask`) somewhere in your `Activity`, and occasionally your thread (again, especially if it's an `AsyncTask`) will require a reference to a `Context` in order to perform some kind of UI update upon the conclusion of its background task.  You will need to make sure that the `Context` (and anything derived from it--like a `TextView` or the like) to which your thread has a reference is non-null, or else it will crash.

You might use `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` to set your `Activity`'s reference to the thread, and then call a setter on the thread to set its `Context` reference (to avoid any related null pointer crash).